# 'pip install --upgrade pip' for python 3.8.1 in Visua Studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

I am entirely new to python and new to Visual Studio on MAC. I come from a Microsoft background.

My quandry:
I received the following message after installing python extension within Visual Studio for MAC :

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What I tried #1:
I tried the command in the terminal:

```
iMac:~ username$ pip install --upgrade pip
~bash: pip: command not found
iMac:~ username$
```

What I tried #2:
Searching on the internet for "You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command." I found, among other things, this site: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/
Being from a Microsoft background this leaves me confused. It seems to say that I may need to install all kinds of things and in the right order. The very very long very technical page is beyond me. How do I find what those things are I need to install and in what order. I scarcely understand the terminology the syntax or how to sort through the long document. Then I don't even know if I'm looking at the right document. Isn't there something that's more clearly written that I a beginner can use to get this resolved so that I can be up and running learning Python?

Please advise.

Comment: Try "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

or

`pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip`

or

`pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`